# Is it possible to create Image (android.media) from bitmap or byteBuffer in android?

Tags: android

If it is possible, please share the **source code**

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score -2):

Image is an abstract class.  You never directly have an Image class, you always have some subclass.  Those subclasses are just generally hidden.

So sure, you can do this.  You'd just have to create your own Image subclass and implement the class interface yourself.  If you're doing that, you can have whatever constructors and source of image data you want.

Comment: Can you please share an example of the Image subclass?